# Windows Explorer hang up constantly

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have a Windows 7 Home Edition laptop, It has an AMD 64 bits.

Constantly the Windows Explorer or the task bar hangs up, after a few clicks with the mouse (task bar) or try to close de Windows explorer I have a message to Reset the application. After that everything works fine until the next hangs up.

This is a constant behavior, I must reset the windows explorer several times during the session.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do some digging to track down the problem.  I suggest you look at [Mark Russinovich's webcasts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963887) to learn about using Microsoft's free [SysInternals Tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default).

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed any updates recently? Some of Microsoft's updates are notorious for causing corruption issues. If you have this update installed try uninstalling it:

```
KB3022345
```

This is the update that caused my laptop's explorer.exe to go insane and almost has me reinstalling Windows.

There are many causes to why explorer.exe can crash, but this is the problem I had. Try running `sfc /scannow` in the command prompt to check for corruption. (This will take awhile.)

When this update was on my PC, explorer crashed all the time when doing almost anything, and the command i listed above just had errors but it couldn't fix anything. I uninstalled it and EVERYTHING worked again.